# Cut command Error: the delimiter must be a single character

Tags: grep, command-history, cut

I am trying the following command on bash-4.3

```
$history | grep history | xargs cut -d ' ' -f1
```

but i am getting the following delimiter Error that I can't get rid of

**cut: the delimiter must be a single character**

I tried removing xargs but it gives a blank output. The whole idea is to get **a** particular command number from the history and then pass it to history -d to delete **that** particular command from the history. Here is just the output of

```
history | grep history



  498  history | grep history | cat | xargs cut -d " " -f1
  500  history | grep history | cat | xargs awk -ifs " "
  501  history | grep history | xargs cut -d " " -f1
  502  history | grep history | xargs cut -d '0' -f1
  503  history | grep history | xargs cut -d 0 -f1
  504* history | 
  505  history | ack history | xargs cut -d ' ' -f1
  506  history | ack history | xargs cut -d ' ' -f1
  507  history | ack history | cut -d ' ' -f1
  508  history | grep history
```

Comment: Try it without the `xargs`.   Although I'm not sure what this command is meant to do...

Comment: @StephenHarris updated post. So the idea is to get a particular command number from the history and then pass it to history -d to delete a particular command from the history

Comment: So you probably want to use `awk` to get the first field.  Something like `history | awk '/command_to_search_for/ { print $1}'`.  That'll return the history number of "command_to_search_for"

Comment: @StephenHarris What is wrong with my command. How can i fix it?

Comment: `cut -d' '` will split on spaces... but there are _multiple_ spaces and so `-f1` will probably just return a space.   `awk {print $1}` is easier to get the first field.  So you could do `history | grep command_to_search_for | awk '{print $1}'`  but that's simpler written with the `history | awk` command I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some explanations:

- You actually want the *second* field, so you need to change to `cut -d ' ' -f 2'.
- `xargs` is not applicable here. What it does is take standard input and passes them as *arguments* to a command. However, `cut` operates on standard input by default, which is what you want. `history | grep history | xargs cut […]` ends up creating commands like `cut […] [some content from the Bash history]'`. To process a series of line numbers printed with a newline after each you'll want to use a `while read` loop:

  ```
  while IFS=$'\n' read -r -u9 number
  do
      history -d "$number"
  done 9< <(history | grep […] | cut […])
  ```
- `some_command | cat | other_command` is completely redundant. `cat` simply copies its standard input to standard output by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
    history | grep history | awk NR==1'{print $8 " " $9 " " $10 " " $11 " " $12 "" $13 }'
xargs cut -d ' '-f1
```

`NR==1`: `awk` will read the cells in the first row of the table, then prints the columns relevant to "xargs cut -d ' '-f1" which are 8-12

Comment: please explain the awk syntax and arguments. Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with my command. How can i fix it?